# iOS SISinusWaveView equivalent?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos

I need to create a wave view that changes based on microphone input, a la iOS 7 Siri. I found out about SISinusWaveView (which you can see [here](https://github.com/raffael/SISinusWaveView), but its only compatible with OS X. Is there any compatible version of this, or an equivalent which works for iOS?

Thanks!

Comment: "As you can see, it claims to be compatible with both iOS and OS X." Actually, no where in `SISinusWaveView`'s github repo do I see anything that says it's compatible with iOS, at all. To make it work with iOS you'd have to refactor the code.

Comment: @DRBeardface right, that was a dumb mistake on my part :p I wrote that first part and then realized it was EZAudio that said it was compatible with both, not SISinusWaveView; so, I rewrote my question--it seems I forgot to press the 'delete' key though :P edited to make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, no problem. Yeah I don't know of an iOS equivalent of this SISinusWaveView, unfortunately, so I'm afraid I can't help you there.

Comment: It's alright :) thanks anyways! I ended up using Siri's visualizer (this is for a jailbreak tweak) however I can't get it to change based on mic input :c